# Using PHP interfaces in Codeigniter

Tags: php, oop, codeigniter

I am trying to find out how can I used PHP interfaces in my MVC design. I want to make sure that the design enforces an interface so that any new module would follow that.

For example:

```
<?php

interface BaseAPI {
     public function postMessage($msg);
}

class ServiceAPI implements BaseAPI {
     public function postMessage($msg) { return $msg; }
}

class Service_Two_API implements BaseAPI {
     public function postMessage($msg) { return "can't do this: ".$msg; }
}

?>
```

I want to do this in CI. Is it possible? how should I design it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what you're asking. If you're asking if you can make the Code Igniter framework follow your Interfaces, you could, but it would require a whole lot of refactoring in their framework, and probably wouldn't be worth the work.

If you're asking if you can add Interfaces for your custom classes while using Code Igniter, of course you can. CI doesn't limit your ability to create custom code, in fact that's what it's there for. I guess the real answer is "What exactly are you asking?".

Comment: How to add Interfaces for your custom classes while using Code Igniter ?

Answer (score 15):

### Here's How to Get CodeIgniter to Load Interfaces Properly

**In your application/config/autoload.php:**

```
// Add "interface_autoloader" to your models array
$autoload['model'] = array('interface_autoloader');
```

**Now create a new class in your application/models folder "interface_autoloader.php":**

```
<?php

class Interface_autoloader {

    public function __construct() {
        $this->init_autoloader();
    }

    private function init_autoloader(){
        spl_autoload_register(function($classname){
            if( strpos($classname,'interface') !== false ){
                strtolower($classname);
                require('application/interfaces/'.$classname.'.php');
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**Now create a new folder in your application folder called "interfaces":**
[image: Example of Interface Usage with CodeIgniter]

**Then just add your interfaces into the "interfaces" folder and you should be able to use them like normal.**

Comment: I just would like to note, due to being voted down, this is not a standard way of doing interfaces in PHP. However, neither is having controllers in a separate folder from your models (CI's standard).

Comment: This is correct and under CI's structure, this is the most logical solution. Why this was downvoted, I'll never know.

Comment: There is a minor problem with this: if the interface is used by something other than a model (like a helper), then the models are loaded AFTER the helper... so it won't see the interfaces yet. +1 anyway, it made me understand how things work a bit better.

Comment: How can the interface be used within a library function (or helper)?

Answer (score 4):

I'm using interfaces in my codeigniter project. I just do it:

Some classes need to extends a personal Controller, so I have created the librarie called Module_Controller extends Controller. This library is autoloaded.

In the same file, I have been declared the interface. So, my file libraries/Module_Controller.php has the following code:

```
class Module_Controller extends Controller{
...
}

interface modular{
...
}
```

In this way, when this file be loaded, the interface will be declared for everyone.

Comment: Actually it's not bad way of organizing things. If the interface modular is a behavior Module_Controller expects for objects that are passed to it then it makes sense. This way you don't impose any kind of object hierarchy on classes that need to work with Module_Controller.

Answer (score 3):

You can create `MY_Loader` class extends `CI_Loader` into application/core and make load your interfaces.

Here has a sample: http://heatherevens.me.uk/2013/11/11/interfaces-in-codeigniter/

Answer (score 0):

Your Interface is working great... Simply require_once it above the controller that will use it then declare a new instance of it from within the controller...

*Controller File:*

```
require_once( "Models/ServiceApi" );

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    private $repository;

    public function __Construct()
    {
        $this->repository = new ServiceApi();
    }

    ...
}
```

To be honest, you'd probably want to be able to do some kind of dependency injection, but considering I do not use codeigniter, I'm unsure of how easy it is to simulate a Factory for the dependant calls to Interface to classes.

Let me give you an example though:

**Dependancy Injection:**

*Factory File*

```
// Not sure how this works for code ignite but the idea is like this:

//$repositoryForController = new ServiceAPI();
$repositoryForController = new Service_Two_API();

$controller = new HomeController( $repositoryForController );
```

*Controller File:*

```
require_once( "Models/ServiceApi" );

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    private $repository;

    public function __Construct( BaseAPI $repo )
    {
        $this->repository = $repo;
    }

    ...
}
```

- So Overview. Your interface and service APIS are fine
- Although your architecture will come out tightly coupled, declaring a new instance of your model in a controller is not completely bad news.
- To get the file into your controller file, just require_once it up above the controller.

Comment: This isn't really what OP asked